# Android: Setting new text on old toast and renew duration

Tags: android, kotlin, toast, duration, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a simple app with a button and click listener on it which displays a toast with the number of clicks that have been performed on the button:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val toast by lazy { Toast.makeText(this, "", LENGTH_LONG) }
    var count = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        button.setOnClickListener { updateToast() }
    }

    private fun updateToast() {
        count++
        toast.setText(count.toString())
        toast.show()
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the duration of the toast is not renewed after each click and after 20 clicks (for example) the toast disappears and never shows again, even if I set its duration again before showing:

```
private fun updateToast() {
    count++
    toast.setText(count.toString())
    toast.duration = LENGTH_LONG
    toast.show()
}
```

I can always cancel the currently displayed toast and create new one, but I wanna know if there is a way to update the text on the existing toast and tell it to stay on the screen for the duration of a newly created toast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if there is, don't do that.

From a user experience point of view, imagine if a `Toast` pops up and says `Your file was saved`, and then it suddenly changes to `Your file wasn't saved`.

Without a well-defined graphical transaction between the two messages, the user is very likely to miss the text update.

That's why the `Toast` is supposed to be an `immutable` element.

If you need to communicate something new, use a different `Toast`.

---

And this is actually a problem in some `Android` devices: two subsequent `Toast` messages often do not `fade-out` and `fade-in` *accentuatedly* enough; and if the text length if quite similar between the two messages, you'll probably not notice the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the same Toast object you can do something like this. As you know each time new object is created but because it's boundary is `method level` so object will be easily catched by `garbage collector`.

```
private fun updateToast(String message) {
        count++

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }
```

and now call this method from your clickListner.

if you want to show a single toast at a time then you can take a help of isShown() method from toast class.

```
public void showAToast (String st){ //"Toast toast" is declared in the class
        try{ toast.getView().isShown();     // true if visible
            toast.setText(st);
        } catch (Exception e) {         // invisible if exception
            toast = Toast.makeText(theContext, st, toastDuration);
            }
        toast.show();  //finally display it
    }
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes, that's an option, but I want to have only one toast on the screen. What you suggest will display multiple stacked toasts.

Comment: yes will be the better option. you can also try snackbar which has far more advantages over toast in the perspective of design and ui/ux.

Comment: This won't work on Android 11+, since toast.getView() always returns null.